# Title Bar On Splash Screen

Tags: android, hide, splash-screen, titlebar

I would like to ask is there any means to hide the title bar from showing it on the splash screen page?
I tried changing the theme through the design page ,

tried

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen`

and

`requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

and

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

but the title bar is still there , is there any way to hide it ?

Regards.

Comment: Have you tried this - https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html#41

Comment: app has stopped working.

Comment: Post your logcat here.

Comment: More information would be nice...

Comment: Unable to start activity component info : java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.hide()' on a null object referenc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really easy! Just add this code before your "setContentView" in your Activity class.
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

[image]

Regards, 
Gabriel

Comment: I need to call requestfeature() before adding a content , i googled but found things that i don't understand. Would you mind to explain it to me?

Comment: I edited my answer and uploaded a picture for more explanation on where you should write the code.

Comment: it doesn't work. title is still there. and requestWindowFeature have to call before super constructor. Because it won't work if you call constructor then only request.

Comment: The code hides the Title Bar perfectly in my app (I write it next to the super constructor). Having your whole code might help.

Comment: public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

Comment: Why does your class extend AppCompatActivity? Change it to Activity.

Answer (score 1):

Add two line above setContentView(R.layout.test_activity);

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    getActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.test_activity);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
in your AndroidManifest.xml file like bellow.

```
 <activity
        android:name=".activity.SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: I can't start my app at all :( it shows unfortunately,app has stopped

Comment: I guess is this one "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme with this activity"

Answer (score 0):

For `AppCompat`, following solution worked for me:

Add new theme style with no action bar in your `styles.xml` and set `parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"`.

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>

</style>
```

Now implement the same theme style to your splash screen activity in `androidManifest.xml`

```
<activity
        android:name=".ActivityName"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"> // apply splash them here 

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Here is result:

[image]